# WPF Screen Display for multiple controls on 60 inches screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have to display 10, same user controls in a row. Each control will contain an image of product on left side and right side will contain the the product's first name, last name and category vertically. The control must be aligned with a proper space between them and text in them, must be readable. I am using a stack panel in a gridview row with each control given a 10% of total width of a window. The problem in my code is, no spaces between controls and text in controls is not readable.

```
  <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Margin="0,0,5,0" >

                            <my:ScannedItemUserControl  x:Name="ScannedProduct12" Margin="0,8,0,8"
                                                        Width="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=MyWindow, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.1}"
                FontSize="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=ScannedProduct12, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.06}"
                                                        />
                            <my:ScannedItemUserControl  x:Name="ScannedProduct11" Margin="0,8,0,8" Width="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=MyWindow, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.1}"
                FontSize="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=ScannedProduct11, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.06}"/>

                            <my:ScannedItemUserControl  x:Name="ScannedProduct10" Margin="0,8,0,8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=MyWindow, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.1}"
                FontSize="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=ScannedProduct10, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.06}"/>

                            <my:ScannedItemUserControl  x:Name="ScannedProduct9"   Margin="0,8,0,8" Width="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=MyWindow, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.1}"
                FontSize="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=ScannedProduct9, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.06}"/>

                            <my:ScannedItemUserControl  x:Name="ScannedProduct8" Margin="0,8,0,8" Width="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=MyWindow, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.1}"
                            FontSize="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=ScannedProduct8, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.06}"/>

                            <my:ScannedItemUserControl  x:Name="ScannedProduct7" Margin="0,8,0,8" Width="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=MyWindow, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.1}"
                FontSize="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=ScannedProduct7, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.06}"/>

                            <my:ScannedItemUserControl  x:Name="ScannedProduct6" Margin="0,8,0,8" Width="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=MyWindow, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.1}"
                FontSize="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=ScannedProduct6, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.06}"/>
                            <my:ScannedItemUserControl  x:Name="ScannedProduct5" Margin="0,8,0,8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=MyWindow, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.1}"
                FontSize="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=ScannedProduct5, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.06}"/>
                            <my:ScannedItemUserControl  x:Name="ScannedProduct4" Margin="0,8,0,8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=MyWindow, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.1}"
                FontSize="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=ScannedProduct4, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.06}"/>

                            <my:ScannedItemUserControl  x:Name="ScannedProduct3" Margin="0,8,0,8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=MyWindow, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.1}"
                FontSize="{Binding 
                                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                       ElementName=ScannedProduct3, 
                                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                                       ConverterParameter=0.06}"/>

                        </StackPanel>


public class PercentageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToDouble(value) *
               System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some code here and let us investigate, this looks to me like you need add containers within your `Grid` and possibly use `ControlTemplate` to add unified look, applying style to it will give you complete control over how you want the content to be displayed and triggers will give you options to add some effects.

Answer (score 1):

A stackpanel will always shrink to fit its children based on their size.

If you do not give the children of the stackpanel a width and/or height (depending on the orientation of the stackpanel) they will have default widths / heights of 0.

Simply give the items in the stackpanel appropriate width and / or height settings.

An easy way to get the spacing of the items in the stackpanel uniform is to use padding or margin.

You can easily set the default padding / margin for all items of a certain type inside the stackpanel by using a scoped style (see example).

```
<StackPanel orientation="vertical">
   <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,5"/>
        </Style>
   </StackPanel.Resources> 
   <Label height="32" horizontalAlignment="stretch"> visible label with spacing </Label>
   <Label> invisible label (does have a margin though) </Label>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: The opening statement of this answer is a bit misleading, whilst the rest of the answer is good. I think the wording is a bit confusing - it should say "a stackpanel will always shrink to fit the size of it's children, it doesn't stretch to fill available space". Also, for this kind of layout, it's preferable to use a grid in my experience, because it allows dynamically sized content and will scale nicely across various resolutions

Comment: I'm not changing to "use a grid instead" though, because a stackpanel could be put inside a scrolling parent if the number of children is variable (or maybe better yet, replaced with an ItemsPanel in that case.)

To op : if there are *always* 10 controls in the panel, you should consider a grid.

Comment: I tried that too but what if the name is too large then one control will take much space than rest and the last one will go out of the page because of unavailability of space within a page

Comment: There are numerous approaches you could take to this, like : -add a scrollbar, or : - put the label in a `ViewBox` that has a fixed size (this will cause the text to scale, so make sure it doesn't scale down too much to be readable if you're going to do that) or simply cut the length of the value you put into the label